# How to check IBM MQ cluster Queue and queue manager is already in cluster in linux?

Tags: ibm-mq

` I need to check MQ queue is already exists in cluster. dspmq command and 
dis q(TEST.QUEUE) CLUSTER. which command is used to check IBM MQ queue is already exists in cluster

Answer (score 1):

`dspmq` is used to display the Queue Manager status.
If you want to find out whether a Cluster already has a Queue in it you want to execute the following MQSC command `DISPLAY QCLUSTER(<Queue Name>) WHERE (CLUSTER EQ <cluster name>)`

However, the response will only be valid if the Queue Manager knows about the Queue:

- If you execute the command on a full repository then you can trust the response as the Full repositories always know everything about the cluster.
- If you execute the command on a partial repository, the Queue Manager will only be able to tell you about the Queue if an application has already attempted to make use of the Queue. Otherwise it won't know whether it exists or not.

Comment: Hi @suganthan-raj Was my answer able to help you or was something missing?